# Excel COUNTIF "Column D" year equals 2015 and Column L equals "15 or greater"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am able to count how many cells there are in Column D with year 2015. And I am able to count how many cells there are in Column L that are 15 or greater. However, I'm looking to combine these two formulas but I don't know how.

The formula I use to count the years is:

> =SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT('Sheet1'!D:D,"YYYY")="2015"))

The formula for counting 15 or greater is:

> =COUNTIF('Sheet1'!L:L,">=15")

**Can someone please provide a way I can combine these two formulas so I can count how many instances there was 15 or greater for the year 2015?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNTIFS() with an `S` allows the ability of multiple criteria and you can bracket the dates:

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!L:L,">=15",'Sheet1'!D:D, ">=" & DATE(2015,1,1),'Sheet1'!D:D, "<=" & DATE(2015,12,31))
```

[image]

---

If your dates are actually text strings that look like dates you can do:

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!L:L,">=15",'Sheet1'!D:D,"*2015*")
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the quick reply. I thought that you couldn't use countif to count how many times a year shows in a column. I inputted this formula but it is returning 0. I checked the formula and there are no errors. So I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: It is working for me.  @go.surf13 you sure your data is on Sheet1?

Comment: I'll keep on testing it. Maybe there is something I didn't do right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: no, the format would not matter as long as Excel sees it as an actual date and not a string that looks like a date.  Change the format to general and the dates should all change to a 5 digit number.  if it stays a date then you have text that looks like a date.

Comment: I'm not too sure. I'm pulling from an access query so the format is General. What formats are you using for both Col D and Col L?

Comment: Then it is coming across as text and not an actual date.  Try this formula: `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!L:L,">=15",'Sheet1'!D:D,"*2015*")`

Comment: @ScottCraner

If I need to find the count for column L >= 15 and find in Column D for a breakdown of each month of 2015 would I just use

    `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!L:L,">=15",'Sheet1'!D:D,"*012015*")`
For January of 2015

    `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!L:L,">=15",'Sheet1'!D:D,"*022015*")`  
For February of 2015